# Custom dropdown to page size on ReactTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm using ReactTable from 'react-table', so I need custom the dropdown whit the options to rows per page, this are the options, are the options by default
[image]

I need remove options that be > 20 and insert others options.
to render the table I'm using this code

```
<ReactTable
   data={ data }
   columns={ tableHeader }
   showPagination={ true }
   defaultPageSize={ number || 4 }
   className="-striped -highlight"
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and was add in the properties this line

```
pageSizeOptions= {[10, 15, 20]}
```